# RQT GUI for sending control_msgs

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rqt-gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently testing out the PID values of an `effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` I created using the `ros_control` package. I was wondering if there already exists a GUI from which I can send `JointTrajectoryController/command` messages to this controller or that I need to create a rosnode/rqt_gui myself. I saw such a GUI being used [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57a70HYQTY0&lc=Ugy_KqXfh5T2wukeZA54AaABAg), but I wasn't able to find it online. I tried using the `rqt_publisher` plugin, but it keeps giving me a `# error evaluating as "list"` error as I  can not get the syntax right.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344358/rqt-gui-for-sending-control_msgs/) by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2020-02-17

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lms95](https://answers.ros.org/users/53716/lms95/) on 2020-04-29**:
Hi!

I'm stuck with the same error. Did you managed to solve it? I would like to make one of the joints move following a sinusoidal wave, so it would be nice to have the Message Publisher running.

I passed the points message as a Python list but I cannot find the correct type, I'm getting this on the terminal:

serialization error: field points[] must be of type [trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectoryPoint]

so, the points[] part is a list but it has not the correct format, I gues...

Thank you

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2020-05-07**:
Hey @lms95. I was not able to send joint trajectory goals to the joint trajectory controller using the `rqt_publisher`. I think this is caused by the fact that the expression field is meant for simple expressions, not multi-line messages, or we are using the wrong syntax. In the end, however, I found several other methods of sending goal commands to the joint_trajectory_controller. The first two methods I currently use are the ones given by @gvdhoorn, namely the `axclient` and the `rqt_joint_trajectory_controller`. Additionally, I also wrote a small action client from which I could send goal command to the joint trajectory controller. Since you want to send a sinusoidal wave, I think the last option works best in your case. You can find a guide on how to build a simple action client in the [actionlib documentation on how to do this](https://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Client%20%28Python%29).

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2020-05-07**:
Lastly, you can of course directly send control commands to a joint_trajectory_controller action service via the terminal by making use of the `rostopic pub`. While doing this you can use the ROS autocomplete feature to create the action server message for you. I, however, do not know a way to send a sinusoidal using this method.  In case you really want to use the `rqt_publisher` I think it is best to open a separate issue in which you state the exact syntax you are currently using.

**Comment by [lms95](https://answers.ros.org/users/53716/lms95/) on 2020-05-07**:
Thanks for the reply! I ended discarding the effort_controller so I get rid of the PID values for the moment and ended publishing via `rostopic pub`. As my plan was to use MoveIt! everything is OK for me now.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[wiki/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller)?

Edit: what is shown in the video is the `axclient` if I'm not mistaken (`rosrun actionlib axclient.py`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2020-02-17**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks a lot! These tools are perfect for testing.

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2020-02-17**:
Based on the recommendations of @gvdhoorn I decided to use the following two tools for tuning my controllers:

- [wiki/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_joint_trajectory_controller)
- [rosrun actionlib axclient.py](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/actionlib/html/axclient_8py_source.html)

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2020-02-18**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks again for your answer! Just one question why did I get -15 karma for this post? The user profile `karma` or `activity` tabs don't specify a reason for the karma drop. Is this a side-effect of you having to delete my accepted answer in which I created a summary of your solution to add your comment as the accepted answer? I created this summary because I did not see a way to accept your comment as the accepted answer or could it just be the result of a hidden downvote (-10 karma). I don't mind the karma drop but I am just curious about what I did wrong so I can adhere to the ROS answers [guidelines](https://answers.ros.org/questions/ask/) next time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-18**:
I converted my comment to an answer and then deselected your answer and selected mine as *the* answer.

That's why you got a `-15`.

I assumed that is what you wanted to do yourself, and seeing this:

> I created this summary because I did not see a way to accept your comment as the accepted answer

it would seem my assumption was correct.

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2020-02-18**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks a lot for the explanation. Next time I will wait a bit for summarizing an answer that is given as a comment or ask a moderator to convert it.

**Comment by [rickstaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/40372/rickstaa/) on 2021-05-21**:
For future reference, in ROS noetic the `axclient.py` was moved under the `ros-noetic-actionlib-tools` package.